# Input field needs to both controlled and uncontrolled

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux

I have an input field which is rendered like this:

```
class InputSection extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.onChange(event.target.name, event.target.value);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <input type="text"
                name="topicInputText"
                value={this.props.formValues['topicInputText']}
                onChange={this.props.onChange}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

There are two (perceived) reasons why I have `value` bound to an entry of the `this.props.formValues` object:

1. I need to pass in a default value
2. I need the ability to reset the input field when the users clicks on a "reset" button. This reset button triggers a redux action which leads to a change in the `formValues` object passed-in as a prop

The `onChange` event handler, which is handled up the component chain, triggers a redux action which updates the store state that drives the `formValues` object passed-in as a prop.

But when I type into the input field using the keyboard I get this console warning:

> Warning: InputSection is changing an uncontrolled input of type text
>   to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
>   to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

I suppose this is because my input component is being "managed" (since I'm binding it's `value`). But, if I can't bind it's `value` how do I set it's initial value or reset the value at a later time?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, though it might fix the warning: your `onChange` in the input should point to `handleChange`, not `this.props.onChange`.

Comment: @anbnyc thanks for catching that...I actually had it right in my actual code but mis-typed when simplifying my example. I updated my code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That generally means you're switching between giving it undefined and defined values.  I'm guessing that `formValues["topicInputText"]` does not exist when this is first rendered.

You'll need to make sure that the initial value you pass in is not `undefined`.